# Creating a folder and sub folder where none exist, but don't if they do

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, I've been working with people on this code, and they have with some help we have come up with this:

This works universally between a Mac and PC.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateFolders()

Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet 'Sheet1
Dim lastrow As Long, fstcell As Long
Dim strCompany As String, strPart As String, strPath As String
Dim baseFolder As String, newFolder As String
Dim cell As Range

Set Sheet1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

With Sheet1

    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    baseFolder = "Lists!$G$1"
     'folders will be created within this folder – Change to sheet of your like.

    If Right(baseFolder, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then _
     baseFolder = baseFolder & Application.PathSeparator

       For Each cell In Range("S3:S" & lastrow)    'CHANGE TO SUIT

           'Company folder - column A

           newFolder = baseFolder & cell.Value
           If Len(Dir(newFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir newFolder

           'Part number subfolder - column C

           newFolder = newFolder & Application.PathSeparator & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
           If Len(Dir(newFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir newFolder

       Next

End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `baseFolder = "Lists!$G$1" `. "Lists!$G$1" is a string here. I haven't see the file but by any chance are you trying this? `baseFolder = Sheets("Lists").Range("$G$1").Value`

Comment: Invalid character on $ in $G$1

Comment: Ah a small typo. Updated it :)

Comment: Thanks, trying it out, but still getting the error...

Comment: I see that @GSerg is helping you out here so I'll step back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> baseFolder = "Lists!$G$1"
> ```

This assigns to `baseFolder` the literal value `"Lists!$G$1"`, not the contents of the cell. You probably meant

```
baseFolder = Woksheets("Lists").Range("$G$1").Value
```

(or `baseFolder = [Lists!$G$1]`, if you prefer that syntax).

---

Also you might find this function useful: [`MakeSureDirectoryPathExists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680352.aspx).

Comment: Ths script above checks if the last character of "Lists!$G$1" is "\". Which it never is.

Comment: So how would I make it work, the link you sent me really doesn't mean anything to me... I hate to say it, but being self taught I've been going by what I see in use...

Comment: it says True\Dakota Systems Inc.

Comment: Try this `baseFolder = Sheets("Lists").Range("$G$2").Value` The path is in `G2` and not `G1` :)

Comment: "True\Dakota Systems Inc. doesn't sound like a valid path to me. I think you need something like C:\True\Dakota Systems or C:\MyFolder\True\Dakota Systmes Inc.

Comment: @MattRidge Well, that is your path that does not exist (which is correct). Now see when `newFolder` gets first assigned with "True". For instance, it may be a value from a cell. The link only shows a function that creates the whole directory tree in one go (you currently create each folder in the path manually), so it's not really relevant to your question, just a hint.

Comment: I hate to say it, but I'm asking because I don't know where to look for the answer, if I did I wouldn't be asking. So please don't beat around the bush and tell me where the error is and why, and how to fix it please. Again I'm self taught, where you see an obvious error I don't.

Comment: @Scott I know it doesn't seem like a valid path, but if we follow the link you provided, the path should be  `C:\Documents and Settings\mridge\Desktop\test`

Comment: @SiddharthRout the last comment I got from you was that you were stepping back. So I decided not to respond.

Comment: @Matt Ridge: No.. See up...`Try this baseFolder = Sheets("Lists").Range("$G$2").Value The path is in G2 and not G1 :) – Siddharth Rout 11 mins ago `

Comment: @MattRidge Put the cursor to the line of code where the `newFolder` variable gets first assigned. Press F9 to set a breakpoint. Run your macro; the execution point will end up on that line, highlighting it in yellow. Move mouse cursor over the `newFolder` variable to see its contents. Press F8 to advance one code line further, or press F5 to continue execution until the breakpoint is reached again (which will happen, as you have a `for each` loop). Examine `newFolder` again. Repeat until the problem is found.

Comment: @SiddharthRout sorry about that, didn't see the comment. Seems to work now, but getting a new error, will have to see about fixing it, hold on.

Comment: @GSerg the error is on the last line, `If Len(Dir(newFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir newFolder` the part `MkDir newFolder` is highlighted. It shows `newFolder = "\Vactor Manufacturing\500272a RevB 5*8" Holes"`

Comment: @MattRidge Well, that would mean `baseFolder` was empty string of this iteration, and because it was taken from a cell, that cell should have contained a value?

Comment: @GSerg that doesn't make any sense, because if that was true wouldn't it not get past the first line of code creating the company folder? Because looking in the test folder, it's adding the company and part numbers. It stops at the line in question for some reason.

Comment: @MattRidge Well naturally, the `*` symbol is not allowed in a path. See [File and Directory Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#file_and_directory_names) for a list of illegal characters. You want to remove or replace them with something else before creating a path.

Comment: Looks like I'll be adding in a function.

Comment: @Scott It looks like I may need to use the Function CleanName you helped with in the other post. using the script above, I've already added the function in the script on my computer.  I just need to know where to add it in the last two bits of formula. It wasn't as clear as yours was, which is a pitty.

Comment: Try this newFolder = baseFolder & CleanName(cell.Value) and newFolder = newFolder & Application.PathSeparator & CleanName(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) You may also want to put it here: baseFolder = CleanName(Sheets("Lists").Range("$G$2").Value)

Comment: Ok, figured out the error, inside the description 500272A RevB, 5/8" Holes, the " is not acceptable. I need to change that, but how do I change a " in Excel VBA when that is used to quote everything?

Comment: I decided to take another path...to correct in Excel itself...

`=IF(Lists!$E$2="pcdos",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($D20,","," ")," "," "),".",""),"/","-"),"""",""))` it's long and annoying, but it does what I need in one line instead of VBA.

Comment: your formula works...  but all you have to do was add the """ to the CleanName function....

Comment: @Scott I tried that, it gave me an error, till I solve it, this will work. It's not beautiful, but it works.